# Kendo Grid Multiselect Dropdown Custom filter Persist state not working

Tags: jquery, kendo-ui, grid, kendo-grid

Please help me -
I am trying persist multiselect dropdown custom filter state using grid.getOptions() and grid.setOptions() but it is not working.

My Code is here with dojo link
dojo url: https://dojo.telerik.com/OwAYAXOP/2

```
function createMultiSelect(element) {
                element.removeAttr("data-bind");

                element.kendoMultiSelect({
                    dataSource: names,
                    change: function (e) {
                        var filter = { logic: "or", filters: [] };


                        var values = this.value();
                        $.each(values, function (i, v) {
                            filter.filters.push({ field: "name", operator: "eq", value: v });
                        });
                        console.log(this.dataSource.data());
                        console.log(values);
                        dataSource.filter(filter);
                    }
                });
            }
 $("#load").click(function (e) {
                var gridnew = $("#grid").data("kendoGrid");
                e.preventDefault();
                var options = localStorage["kendo-grid-options"];
                var optionsJSON = JSON.parse(options);

                optionsJSON.columns[1].filterable.ui = createMultiSelect;

                if (optionsJSON) {
                    gridnew.setOptions(optionsJSON);

                }
            });
```